# index all tags in nebula graph version 3.6+

Tags: nebula-graph

our team reported that in Nebula graph v.3.6 didn't need to add an index for all tags.

we need an index to use search in properties of all tags. At the start of the spring boot app, we check it. if not created, create an index.

how can I define indexing for all tags or how can I configure it.

via nebula docker or via spring boot code in startup?